# How to generate gtsummary table for each indication as rows and the percentage of participants in each category as the summary statistic

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have a data.table; mydata in which each participant has multiple indications for surgeries. I have used dcast to convert the data into wide format and then used gtsummary to get the summary table. However, the summary table is not as I desire it to be. Instead of counting number of patients in each category of indications it counts the vector as observations and gives wrong summary statistics. For example, 6 patients had infection in this data, but in the summary table it appears as shown below.

```
    library(data.table)
    library(tidyr)
    library(dplyr)
    libray(gtsummary)
    
    participant.index <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7)
    indication.surgery <- c(
      "ibs",
      "infection", 
      "infection",
      "infection",
      "infection",
      "ibs",
      "infection",
      "infection",
      "ibs",
      "tumour",
      "tumour"
    )
    
    mydata <- data.table(participant.index, indication.surgery)
    
    # Reshape data from long to wide format
    wide_data <- dcast(mydata, participant.index ~ indication.surgery, fun.aggregate = length)
    
    #get gtsummary of the data
    table = gtsummary:: tbl_summary(wide_data[, !"participant.index"])

This gives output like this:
```

|Characteristic |   | N = 7|
|:--------:|:------:|:---:|
|ibs    |            | 3 (43%)|
|infection| 0        |3 (43%)|
|     |1      |2 (29%)|
|     |2      |2 (29%)|
|tumour |  0         |6 (86%)|
|    |2           |1 (14%)|
n (%)

Required output is:

| Indication for surgery | n | N (%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Infection | 6 | 4/7 (57.14%) |
| Ibs | 3 | 3/7 (42.85%) |
| Tumour | 2 | 1/7 (14.28%) |

(n = number of events; N = number of patients in each category)

Please let me know how do I do get the desired output? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your patient assignments, but assuming the participant index denotes individual patients, only patients 1, 2, 3 and 5 had an infection (3 and 5 had 2, while the others had one), and patient 7 had 2 tumors, according to `mydata`, the way it is constructed. I see no fault in the code, based on the example data.

Comment: Thanks @ user12728748.But that code does not give me the summary the way I want it. I was looking for output that I have mentioned in the required output table. I am not sure how to modify the code to get that. All I want is how many infections events occurred in all patients, i.e., two patients developed twice and two developed once. That gives number of infection events = 6. So we see that 4 patients developed 6 events of infection. Percentage of people who developed infection (4/7)*100 = 57.14%

Comment: Guys, can anyone please let me know how do I get the desired output using gtsummary?